# Why doesn't this solution work for finding mode of an array in Ruby (without using hash)

Tags: ruby, arrays

Without using hash, I need to return an array of mode(s) given an input of an array.  I put this together as a proposed solution but am having a hard time understanding why it won't work.

```
def mode(arr)

    count_me=[];
    results=[];

    // for each unique array element, pushes the count of how many times that element occurs to the array "count_me"
    arr.uniq.each{|i|count_me.push(arr[i].count);} 

    //sorts the array of counts in reverse order
    count_me.sort.reverse;

    //for each unique array element, pushes the element to the results array if the count  of that element equals the highest value in the count_me array 
    arr.uniq.each{|i| results.push(arr[i]) if arr[i].count==count_me[0]};

    //returns results array
    puts results;

end
```

Comment: I am not clear. But it seems `count_me.sort.reverse` has no meaning( as you are not storing sorted reverse array), thus you need to use *bang* version of `reverse` and `sort`. Like `count_me.sort!.reverse!`.

Comment: You should provide an input sample.

Comment: Ruby is generally allergic to semi-colons at the end of lines. It's extremely unusual to see them used so liberally as those have no semantic meaning here. If you're coming from a PHP, Perl or C background, it's okay to let go of them!

Comment: You can use `//`comments in Ruby?!

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? As it is, it does not even run.

Comment: OMG How can you use `//` for the comments???

Comment: Hey! Go easy.. I'm really new to Ruby and just switching over.. still thinking in "//" and not "#"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hashes, but I'm not sure why that matters.

```
 def mode arr
  arr.uniq.map { |e| [e, arr.count(e)] }.sort_by(&:last).tap do |c|
    return c.select { |p| p[1] == c[-1][1] }.map(&:first)
  end
end
```

You can even make that a one-liner if you don't mind 120 character lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you loop through an array with `each`, the parameter for the block (in this case `i`) already *is* the element of the array (`arr[i]` if `i` were an index variable).

So, if the elements of the array have a method `count`, it would look like this:

```
arr.uniq.each{|element| count_me.push(element.count) }
```

If, however, you want to count the appearances of an element within the array, you need to rewrite your code to something like the following:

```
occurrences = {}
arr.each do |element|
    occurrences[element] = 0 unless occurrences.has_key?(element)
    occurrences[element] += 1
end
```

The hash `occurrences` now holds a 'list' of all the unique array elements (as keys) with their occurrence count (as values).

If I understand your code correctly, it should return an array of the elements which occur the most – is that right? In this case, I'd suggest something like this:

```
def mode(array)
    occurrences = {}
    array.each do |element|
        occurrences[element] = 0 unless occurrences.has_key?(element)
        occurrences[element] += 1
    end
    highest = Hash[occurrences.sort_by{|k, v| -v}]
    highest.keep_if{|k, v| v == highest.values[0]}
    highest.keys
end
```

The method now counts the occurrences of the array elements, stores them in an array (`occurrences`), sorts them by value and keeps only those with the same value as the highest element (in `highest`). It then returns an array of 'original' values of these highest elements.

Comment: This is a good answer but for the part where the question says "without using a hash".

Comment: Thanks and nicely explained!  If I could use hashes, this would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, you can always write a brute-force solution to this:

```
array = %w[ a b a a c d a a b e e f e ]

array.sort.uniq.each do |value|
  puts '%s %d' % [ value, array.count(value) ]
end
```

This will only work well for trivially tiny datasets. Anything into the thousands of unique elements will start to get painfully slow.